# Shrinking the text in verbatim mode

Tags: spacing, verbatim

I need to deal with loads of code lines in verbatim mode and append them to the appendix. That is, I may not need to show them in a fancy way but I want them to occupy least amount of space. As you could see in the following figure, the text occupy a lot of space. I also need them to have a fix indent from right and left, so by keeping as many in a line, they indentation varies. 
 [image]

Comment: It is a lot easier to use `listings` instead of the plain `verbatim` env

Comment: but in listings I cannot deal with some logic symbols like ->

Comment: Err add `\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,columns=fixed}`  and it is the same (more or less) as `verbatim`

Comment: you appear to have a blank line between each line of text? to make it smaller you can use `\small` before `begin{verbatim}`

Answer (score 2):

Would this be close to what you seek? The proposed solution utilizes `fancyvrb` package where

1. `xleftmargin/xrightmarin (dimension)` commands for indentation to add at the start/end of each line (Default: 0pt—no left/right margin) is readily available.
2. However, this solution also defines `myindent` macro taking one length argument for manual indentation within `Verbatim` environment.
3. Furthermore, the shrinking of text is via `resizebox` from `graphicx`. The outer frame can be removed by removing the `frame=single` key.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,graphicx}
\newcommand\myindent[1]{
\makebox[#1]{}
}
\begin{document}
Before:
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

\myindent{1cm} pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

\myindent{2cm} pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred4(s19).

pred5(s16).

pred6(s10,s12,s17,s11,s14).

logic symbols like ->
\end{Verbatim}

After:
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,commandchars=\\\{\}, xleftmargin=1cm,xrightmargin=1cm]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

\myindent{1cm} pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

\myindent{2cm} pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred4(s19).

pred5(s15).

pred6(s10,s12,s17,s11,s14).

logic symbols like ->

\end{minipage}
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 (and I also borrowed your example to save typing the data:-)

Answer (score 1):

Please always provide a complete example document, Thanks to Jesse, I stole this one from the other answer.

You can use `\small` or any other font size to reduce the size of the verbatim:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-3cm}
Before:
\begin{verbatim}
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).

    pred4(s19).

    pred5(s16).

    pred6(s10,s12,s17,s11,s14).

    logic symbols like ->
\end{verbatim}

After:
{\small
\begin{verbatim}
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
pred3(s11,s17,s11,s19,s10).
    pred4(s19).
    pred5(s16).
    pred6(s10,s12,s17,s11,s14).
    logic symbols like ->
\end{verbatim}}

\end{document}
```